# Canon printer TS8220 ink cartridges

Tags: printer, ink

Canon printer TS8220 has stopped printing. I have tried all the suggestions to reset. The PB ink cartridge is empty. Could this be the problem, although the printer was working previously with this cartridge empty.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be helpful for alternative suggestions and answers if you write the exact error message that the printer shows in either its display or on the computer.

But yes, an empty cartridge could be the problem.

If it really worked before with the cartridge being fully empty (and not just low on ink), perhaps it was with print jobs that didn't require ink from that cartridge. But it sounds strange that it would print at all with an empty cartridge; it's quite normal for printers not wanting to print anything if one of the cartridges is empty.

Try replacing the empty cartridge with a new one and see if that solves the problem; I expect it will.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 possibilities:

1. In the past the PB cartridge was "low" and now it's "empty". The printer works fine when a cartridge is low, but stops when it is empty.
2. In the past, the driver was set to print with black in only; this was changed and now it is set to print with all inks. This should be selectable from Printing Preferences.